# How to determine if a field is returned by a SOQL query

Tags: apex

As a really rough example let's say I have 2 queries:

```
list<BU__c> l_bu = [Select field1__c, field__3 From BU__c];

list<BU__c> l_bu = [Select field2__c, field__3 From BU__c];
```

So when I iterate through the list how I can test if field1__c was returned or field2__c was returned?

I can't use `if(bu.field1__c == null)` as it will throw an exception that it was not returned in the query.

thanks!

lee

EDIT: I'll add a bit more information to help. I have a function that takes an ID as a parameter. I would like to know if I need to pass in field1__c or field2__c.

I'm building a `MAP<ID,sObject>` and the sObject either contains field1__c or field2__c. So when I call the function it either needs to pass in bu.field1__c or bu.field2__c.

Clear as mud?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(bu));
if (m.get(String.valueOf(BU__c.Field1__c)) == null) {
    // ...
}
```

as Apex maps don't have the exception throwing logic that SObjects do for unqueried fields.

Example of it working:

```
Account a = [select Name from Account limit 1];
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(a));
System.assertEquals(true, m.get(String.valueOf(Account.Name)) != null);
System.assertEquals(false, m.get(String.valueOf(Account.Phone)) != null);
```

Comment: Tried that and still got the error. Probably going to have to not be lazy and just make 2 for loops :-)

Comment: @LeeFranke Would expect it to work based on the above example that works. But the serializing and deserializing would be a last resort; if you can restructure your code some other way to solve the problem do that.

Comment: It worked! I had a typo when I first ran it.

Comment: Not sure if this is more or less overhead than just running another for loop. But that is another question :-)

Comment: As an alternative, you can *catch* the exception, which will be a System.SObjectException. Something like `Object fieldValue; try { fieldValue = record.field1__c; } catch(SObjectException e) { /* Field was not queried */ } if(fieldValue == 'some value') { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a SOQL FOR Loop to iterate through results.  You can't apply a comparison for the entire list on a specific field.

```
      FOR( BU__c bu : [Select field1__c, field__3 From BU__c]){

        if(bu.field1__c == null){
            //do some action or exit loop
        }

      }
```

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm

Also, if you want to verify for a single sObject, you can simply apply the "LIMIT" clause to the end of your query to limit results to 1, which returns a single sObject.  In this case, you will need to use IF statements to compare whether there is a value populated:

```
BU__c bu = [Select field1__c, field__3 From BU__c LIMIT 1];

if(bu.field1__c == null){

       //do some action or exit loop

}
```

Comment: edited the question to show that @LeeFranke was asking something else. His original question already correctly had l_bu for the query result and bu for the single sobject instance that he was working on. But it's clearer now.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Yeah, single sObject completely changes answer.  I'll consider revising.

Comment: And he says "when I iterate through the list...". I'm going to put his orginal queries back.